# How to enumerate Extjs grids in a form

Tags: extjs

I need to be able to find all grids for a given form. This is a simplified version of what I'm doing:

```
function formEnumerate(form)
{
    form.getForm().items.each(function (element)
    {
         // gets form elements but not grids
    });
}
```

Can I get the grids from `form`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Ext4, you can use the component query method:

```
var grids = form.query('gridpanel');
```

In 3.x you can use the findByType method: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.Container-method-findByType

Comment: Updated with a method you can use for 3.x.

Comment: Thank you! Note that I didn't think this worked at first, as it returns a basic array rather than an enumerable collection - use a for loop rather than .each()